# Rails copy management

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, content-management-system

I was looking for a Gem or tool to integrate into my Rails app that will allow a non-technical person to change the text on our site's marketing pages. We are currently using Copycopter, however we can't run it on the free Heroku tier anymore. Furthermore CopyCopter was built for Postgres which is not really part of our stack we use Amazons MySQL on RDS.

Are there any gems/tools I should be aware of that would help me out? Thanks!